# How to get html source synchronously to a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have scanned the tag [[cefsharp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cefsharp) and the question I am asking is present in similar forms (please reconsider the duplicate question action).

I am unable to solve what I think should be a simple request. To get the html source of the page in the browser control and interact with winform controls synchronously.

I am weak on the asynchronous side but managed to get the source using a couple of ways I garnered from this tag [[cefsharp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cefsharp). However, any interaction with winform controls triggered from an async event which "locks" in any subsequent method calls to be in a async "mode", and therefore any winform control interaction.

**Example 1:**

```
private async void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, 
                                        CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsLoading)
    {
        //-- WORKS, but ...
        string html = await Task.Run(Browser.GetSourceAsync);


        //-- .. when calling other methods which interact with winform controls,
        //-- I have to do so in the following way because I am not on the UI thread.
        //-- therefore every control needs a block like this
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                txtSource.Text = html;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            txtSource.Text = html;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**
Another example I have working partly is this method. However, calling from a button click works, while the browser event does not

```
public string GetSource()
{
    string result = null;

    if (Browser.IsBrowserInitialized && !Browser.IsDisposed && !Browser.Disposing)
    {
        Task<string> task = Browser.GetSourceAsync();
        var complete = task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!t.IsFaulted)
            {
                result = t.Result;
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.Default);
        complete.Wait();

    }
    return result;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //-- WORKS
    txtSource.Text = GetSource();
}

private void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, 
                                        CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsLoading)
    {
        //-- DOES NOT WORK. Hangs on waiting for the complete.Wait();
        //-- note: this method is not async and neither the button too.
        txtSource.Text = GetSource();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it help if I answered with how to avoid the repetition of `Invoke` by abstracting it?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18429217/932418) use webbrowser control but the same rules apply.

Comment: The first thing thats obvious is that calling `Wait` blocks the current thread. So don't use  that. I guess there is also a problem in `Browser.GetSourceAsync`. Post the source of that method

Comment: @Eser That is an awful answer. Using `Thread` directly should be avoided

Comment: @Sievajet That's the first example...

Comment: @Sievajet this is the source for GetSourceAsync() https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs

Comment: apparently the `Wait` call is causing a deadlock. You should return a task from `GetSource` and it should work

Comment: UI programming should always be done in an async fashion. Interacting with CefSharp in a sync fashion is not recommend or supported. You can use extension methods like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L141 to simplify your code.

Comment: looks like the way I will handle this is store the html in the txtSource and then attach a changed event on that for the rest of my winform to work how i want it

Comment: And why are you doing `await Task.Run(Browser.GetSourceAsync);` in example 1? Why not just `await Browser.GetSourceAsync()`? Then you won't need those invokes.

Comment: @evt because that method will need to be async (for the await) and then my other methods driven by which domain or url that are fired from that event to process the data will also have to be async and those methods interact with the form ui controls so I would have to delgate "execute" any interaction with those. all simply because getting the source is async. I did not have this problem with the c# browser control as sucky as it was.

Comment: Just use an extension method